# How to run a command line script every Friday at 3:00 AM automatically?

Tags: windows, command-line

I currently use SWFTools via command line on my computer. I have two commands that I want to run every Friday at 3:00 AM automatically. However, I want to run the two scripts in a specific order. This is what I have:

At 3:00 AM on Friday I want to run this first:

```
.\swfcombine -o "C:\users\****\My Documents\****\****\****.swf" --dummy -y 50 "C:\users\****\My Documents\****\****.swf"
```

Then this:

```
.\swfrender "C:\users\****\My Documents\****\****\****.swf" -o "C:\users\****\My Documents\****\****.png"
```

How can I make this happen automatically? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Task Scheduler on a Windows system.

Create Basic Task Wizard:
Trigger: Weekly
Recur every: 1 weeks on:
X Friday

Start a program

Put your two lines into a bat file, then put that file into your "Start a Program".

Your bat file might look something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM This program first combines then renders swf files as png 
"C:\Path\to\swfcombine" -o "%USERPROFILE%\Path\to\****.swf" --dummy -y 50 "%USERPROFILE%\Path\to\****.swf"
.\swfrender "%USERPROFILE%\Path\to\****.swf" -o "%USERPROFILE%\Path\to\****.png"
```

In Windows 8, the task scheduler looks like this:
[image: Windows 8 Task Scheduler]

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm not very familiar with bat files. Would I just place the lines I used in a file and call it file.bat?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: Great! I have another question, would I include the line "cd C:\users\****\..." in the bat file? Sorry for the questions, I'm still learning. Haha!

Comment: You should be able to use `%USERPROFILE%` in place of the `C:\Users\<username>\` part of the path. You don't need to include the `cd` statement if you specify the exact path to the executables (`%USERPROFILE%\path\to\program\swfrender`) on those command lines.